# Function error : argument 3 matches multiple formal arguments

Tags: r

This code :

```
f1 <- function(abc , ac , df){
  list(f1 = abc , f2=ac , f3 = df)
}

f1(1,2,a=3)
```

returns error :

```
Error in f1(1, 2, a = 3) : argument 3 matches multiple formal arguments
```

Is reason for this error a is being matched by arguments `abc` , `ac` in function `f1` due to `function partial matching` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a named argument doesn't match exactly any formal arguments,
R tries to apply partial matching *by prefix*.
`abc` and `ac` both start with "a",
and R doesn't know which one it should use,
so it raises an error.

If you use `f1(1, 2, ac=3)`,
then R will assign `3` to `ac`,
and then it will assign the remaining values to the remaining unassigned parameters,
so `1` to `abc` and `2` to `df`.